# How's stat function used in Perl?

Tags: file, perl, stat

Can anyone help me to understand the meaning of below line?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::stat;

...

sub rootdev { return (stat readlink)[0] == (stat "/")[0]; }
my @vols = shuffle map {/.*\/([0-9]+)/} grep {not rootdev} grep {-e readlink} grep {-l} glob("/dev/shm/v/*");

...
```

There is submodule like above, but I cannot understand the meaning of `stat readlink)[0] == (stat "/")[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

The input of the submodule `rootdev` is `grep {-e readlink} grep {-l} glob("/dev/shm/v/*")` .

So, firstly get the filelist from `/dev/shm/v/` directory and filter with `grep` only for symlink.

Then check the device id(first array info of `stat` function) and compare it with root device.

It's for checking the pointed device of symlink in `/dev/shm/v` is root device or not to include or exclude whatever.

Answer (score 1):

`( LIST )[ LIST ]` is called a list slice.

It returns the elements of the first list identified by the indexes returned by the second list.

```perl
say for ( 'A'..'Z' )[ 0, 1, 2, 25 ];   # A B C Z
```

That means that `( stat ... )[0]` returns the first value returned by `stat`.

---

The builtin `stat` operator returns information about the file. It returns a number of values, the first is the device id of the file.

So, when using the builtin `stat`, `( stat $path )[0]` returns the device id of the file specified by `$path`.

---

But you're not using the built `stat`. You're using the one from File::stat. In that situation the sub you posted doesn't do anything useful. It effectively does `return 0` because it's comparing the memory addresses of two different objects. The following is adjusted for using File:stat's `stat`:

```perl
use File::stat;

sub rootdev { return ( stat readlink )->dev == ( stat "/" )->dev; }
```

or

```perl
use File::stat;

sub rootdev { return stat( readlink )->dev == stat( "/" )->dev; }
```

---

Finally, it's really weird that the sub requires that its input be provided using `$_` instead of as an argument.